# Heroku play scala always runs in Prod mode

Tags: scala, heroku, playframework, sbt

When I run "sbt ~run" I can see that mode is set Dev as expected. However, when I run "heroku local web" the server runs in Prod mode. Any idea how I can get this set to Dev mode? Do I have to set any variable with heroku config CLI ? My intention is to test with heroku local before pushing to Heroku git.

Have tried this in my Procfile:

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/myapp -Dhttps.port=${PORT} -Dhttp.port=disabled -Dhttps.keyStore=conf/generated.keystore -Dlogback.configurationFile=conf/logback.xml -Dapplication.mode=DEV
```

But still it shows Prod. When server runs, the conf file is set programmatically with "-Dconfig.resource=root-dev.conf".

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use environment variables for the `application.mode` in some fashion (after all, that's what environment variables are for: changes specific to an environment). There are a few way you could do this, one is to create an `APPLICATION_MODE` env var, and use it in your `Procfile` thusly:

```
-Dapplication.mode=${APPLICATION_MODE:-DEV}
```

This will set `-Dapplication.mode` from `APPLICATION_MODE` and default to `DEV` if the env var is not set. Then you can set the env var on Heroku like this:

```
$ heroku config:set APPLICATION_MODE="PROD"
```

Or you could put the whole `-Dapplication.mode=DEV` in `JAVA_OPTS` in your `.env` file in your local repo like this:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Dapplication.mode=DEV"
```

The `heroku local` command will pick up `.env` and load it. In this way you don't need to change anything on Heroku.